# How to add to the library search path for custom plugins

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm running a `gz-sim` (Garden) simulation starting from [PX4](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot) where I want to include a custom plugin into my model. The model works if I copy-paste the .so file to any of the default search locations, i.e.

```
- /home/anton/.gz/sim/plugins/
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-7/plugins/
- /home/anton/.ignition/gazebo/plugins/
```

However, I'd prefer to set an environment variable (as in Gazebo-Classic) to tell gazebo to search for additional plugins. In gazebo-classic I could do

```
export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH="$PWD:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH"
```

but this doesn't seem to work in `gz-sim` garden.

Is there any other way to add to the library search path of `gz-sim`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29280/how-to-add-to-the-library-search-path-for-custom-plugins/) by [antbre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/60527/antbre/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Found the answer myself. The new path variable is

```
GZ_SIM_SYSTEM_PLUGIN_PATH
```

The best overview I found of the naming conventions in the `gz-garden` is in this [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1VP7h1jirRdJpM0BsV42RgXsMPeDE6D7ePV1Mg1jch-U).

---

Originally posted by [antbre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/60527/antbre/) with karma: 1 on 2023-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2327/mz/) on 2023-07-14**:
Hi, thanks for looking over the presentation. For others, the variable can be found by `gz sim --help`. Also, that variable is documented in a tutorial for how to find resources https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/7/resources.html